# Android ternary operator

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I am trying to do a simple ternary operator but I have an error I can't see. This is my code:

```
public void setVisibility(boolean isVisible) {
    View adView = ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.adView);
    isVisible? adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) : adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

I get the error : Not a statement. Does someone know where is my error?

Comment: Ternany operators can't be used on calling methods but on variables instead

Comment: use this  adView.setVisibility(isVisible?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);

Comment: Why does this question have -6 downvotes? I don't really see what's the unforgivable error in it

Answer (score 25, accepted):

it is not a statement

```
int visibility = isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
adView.setVisibility(visibility);
```

or in one line

```
adView.setVisibility(isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator are usually used for assignment or method argument. I think you shouldn't use ternary operator to select an action, but to select a reference to an object to use.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It is an explaination about why it doesn't work and a suggestion to solve it : use ternary operation for reference or variable.